# A lot of information on one page

Tags: gui-design, software

I'm working on some software for a startup. We have a tool where you can see and analyse data. We are growing and our tool is getting bigger and bigger.

The problem that i'm facing is that the pages in the tool are getting too long.
 1. the usabilty is getting worse because you have to scroll far to reach the latest module.
 2. the loading time of the pages is getting longer.

My idea is to collapse all modules, but as designer i'm not sure what i think about that. Because we are een analyzing tool, where the overview of the data is our unique sellingpoint it doesn't feel right to hide modules. Everything in the page is equal important. Such that i can't split the page.

Has anyone experience with pages that are too long and what was your solution?

Comment: *"Everything in the page is equal important."*
That is how every product owners starts with the negotiation. But then, it is just a start.

Comment: Have you thought of start thinking with user flows? Let's say a user wants to perform an action. What should they do to perform this action? As for the modules, why doesn't each module have a page for it? Also, could you share some screens in order to help you easier? It is quite broad question.

Comment: Doubt that "everything in the page is equal important". It never does. It's a misconception of lazy management. "I need to see all the data" and then they are overwhelmed. **Individual data** or **all the data** is not important, The relationship between the data and the comparison of these indicators is what should be shown and, if the user requires it, show the individual data.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe collapse everything in sections, like you're thinking, and show a summary data point on each collapsed element.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fawva9m.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Or provide a dashboard page that shows a summary data point for each category and links off to detail pages for each.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about a secondary navigation/menu. Vertical to left of the module text. listing all the modules and anchoring to the specific module when clicked. The full text would still scroll but the user has the option to choose a preferred module. The module menu should always be in view even when the user starts to scroll.